# What does log entry "onDestroy leaving the lights on for com.myapp" mean?

Tags: android

I searched all over the internet and this site and I can't figure this out.. Is this just a tongue and cheek way of Android letting me know that my app is at some point in the cycle?  I all of a sudden started seeing this entry in logcat, and I am just very curious to know what it really means.. thanks.

Comment: What do you have in onDestroy method of this Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *specifically* what this means since it almost certainly depends on the application (if it were an Android thing, your searches probably would have shown something). But I can take an educated guess.

While the `onDestroy` method may be usually expected to shut down as much as possible of an application, re-creating that application state may take some time.

Hence, a clever coder may decide to maintain some state so as to quicken the startup process next time around.

That's what "leaving the lights on" usually means, an example being keeping the bathroom light on for the next person to use it even though you're finished (somewhat wasteful, unless the next person is going in immediately).

For a more programming-related example, let's say your application requires a long-running calculation when it starts. Rather than doing that each time, you would "leave the lights on" by ensuring that it was stored somewhere and could be easily restarted.

Answer (score 1):

This is MapActivity who signify to you that you didn't shutdown location and/or map provider properly.

He think you are a dirty guy and cleaned the mess behind you, but he's upset now.

You have to solution :

- Never do it again.
- Offer flowers to MapActivity to be forgiven.

Have fun !

Comment: sure I will do as u said sir...;)